# Typescript/Vue 3 -- find() value within an array of objects. Object is of type 'unknown'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How do I resolve the following typescript error? For context, I am using the Vue 3 Composition API where I ultimately am using the result to specify whether or not a default option value should be `<option ... selected v-if="!isMatch">`.

`Object is of type 'unknown'.`

The error is highlighting the second 'option'.

```js
props:{
    value: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
    },
    options: {
        required: true,
        type: Array,
    },
}
setup(props){
    const isMatch = () => props.options.find(option => {
        return option['code'] === props.value
    })
    return { isMatch }
}
```

***Example 'Options' Data***

```json
[
    {
        "code": "CA",
        "name": "Canada"
    },
    {
        "code": "US",
        "name": "United States"
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you share the `props` setup part? By the looks of how you are using it on the template, I think RoToRa is right, you might want to use `Array.prototype.some` instead of `find`. Need more context here.

Comment: @YomT. Props added.

Comment: use `computed` for `isMatch`

Comment: @Lynx Thanks, but receiving the same error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following a bit of refactoring, I came up with this via the [Vue Docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props). I required the addition of two interface definitions and the `PropType` import.

```js
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'

interface Option {
    code: String,
    name: String
}

interface Options extends Array<Option>{}

export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        id: {
            required: true,
            type: String,
        },
        title: {
            required: true,
            type: String,
        },
        selections: {
            required: true,
            type: Array as PropType<Options>
        }
        modelValue: {
            required: true,
            type: String,
        },
    },
    setup(props) {
        const isMatch = () =>
            props.selections.some(
                selection => selection['code'] === props.modelValue
            )

        return { isMatch }
    },
})
```

Comment: Yep, it's a common gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

`.find()` returns an matching object from the array, but you seem to just want a boolean saying if such an object exists, so you should be using [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead.

BTW, you can simplify the arrow function by just using an expression instead of using `return`:

```
const isMatch = () => props.options.some(option => option['code'] === props.value)
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'm still needing to resolve the "Object is of type 'Unknown'" error.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that would help. I don't have any other ideas.